# How to recognize string interpolation text as HTML in an Aurelia template

Tags: javascript, html, aurelia

I'm trying to add marked-up text to a div in an Aurelia template through string interpolation, however the HTML in it is being rendered as literal text rather than as HTML.  So for example:

```
// in view-model
htmlString = "Line 1 <br> Line 2";

// in view template
<template>
  <div>
    ${htmlString}
  </div>
</template>
```

gets rendered as

```
Line 1 <br> Line 2
```

and not as

```
Line 1  
Line 2
```

Is there a way do this so that the interpolated text is recognized as HTML and not as a string literal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
<template>
 <div innerhtml.bind="htmlString"></div>
</template>
```

But you need to be *extremely* careful in using this with any user generated HTML, as there is little, if any sanitization of the HTML that gets injected in to the DOM when using this.